# Why would Mike need a part time job as a PI for Saul?

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

In *Breaking Bad*, because Mike works for Gus Fring, presumably he should be all set financially. Also Mike is apparently loyal to Gus. Why would he need a part time job as a PI for Saul Goodman on top of his multiple activities for Gu's operation? This part-time job might even be a conflict of interests. Also Mike is obviously old and not very fit - why does he want extra work?

Why would Gus allow his loyal hit man do part time work on the side?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Mike has not spent a dime of Fring's drug money, which is revealed when he is first interrogated by the DEA. All Mike's earnings from Fring's employment are put away for his grand-daughter. Thus perhaps his PI work for Goodman covers his living costs.

Technically this might be a conflict of interest, but these are not moral, law-abiding citizens. Additionally, working for Goodman allows Mike to keep an eye on Walt and Jesse, who are very much part of Fring's interests. This would explain why Gus would allow Mike to work for Goodman. Now if Goodman were to ask Mike to tail Fring, Fring might have put a stop to Mike's extra work.

Comment: I am not with you on "this might be a conflict of interest, but these are not moral, law-abiding citizens". AFAIK in all the movies I've ever seen gangsters demand absolute loyalty and do not tolerate conflict of interests - why should Gus be an exception. Very careful as Gus is, can't he see that Mike's extra activities can bring police attention to him?

Comment: I meant by the line you quoted, that legally representing two clients who work closely would be a conflict of interest. But as I explain, it isn't really because Fring has interest in keeping tabs on Walt, Jesse, and in turn Goodman. I sure Mike is reporting back to Gus on these things.

This would not bring police attention on Fring. Fring is regarded as a respected businessman and active community member, in no way a suspect for the drug operations in the area. Mike has PI licenses, so his work for Goodman is not illegal. Even if questioned by police for PIing, it isn't connected to Fring.

Comment: Also, anytime Goodman's request interfere with Fring's interest, Mike does not do them. He even states in one episode that the boss wouldn't like it (referring to Fring). Fring can clearly see that Mike is fiercely loyal.

Comment: I am not sure about this: " Fring has interest in keeping tabs on Walt, Jesse, and in turn Goodman". Apparently Mike is already working for Saul as his PI by the time Saul is kidnapped by Walt and Jesse, right?

Comment: I believe so. But even at this time there was mention of a kingpin, who was likely Fring. He wasn't selling blue meth, but he has some substandard product. Having Mike work for Saul (even before Walt and Jesse) may just be for connections. Saul basically works with every shady person in that area, so it is a good way for Fring to search for excellent cooks, dealers to sell his product, and gunmen.

Comment: A completely different possibility is that (as previously mention) Mike doesn't use his drug money. He has a lawyer who takes care of saving it for his daughter. Perhaps to protect the chance the lawyer & his money will be safe, he must use a different lawyer to protect him in criminal activities (like when the DEA brings him in). He likely can't afford Goodman, as his only source of income can't be used for fear of police noticing it, so he offers his PI services in return for Goodman's legal services.

Comment: ^ in the above case, Fring would be allowing Mike to do PI work for Goodman, because he trusts Mike to not let it interfere with Fring's operation and he needs Mike to be protected from police (since he is essential to the drug operation).

Comment: Mike is legally employed by Los Pollos Hermanos, in charge of corporate security. This is later discussed when Hank and Steve are interrogating him. As such, he already has a source of legal income - his salary is legal, technically not "drug money". What am I missing?

Comment: That is an excellent point I forgot about. I didn't fully understand the legal reasons for not using the money in the first place. The other men used their money and ended up in jail, but for some reason not spending any kept Mike free. It may be legal, but Mike isn't willing to use it because of that reason. So he needs an actual legal income. The Los Pollos Hermanos income appears legal on the books, but if investigated it could be seized by the feds (which it was). Mike's incoming from his PI gigs can't be legally seized.

Answer (score 4):

The only reason he would 'need' a job working for Goodman would be because it provides him with a legal income source. This allows him to 'hide in plain sight' like Mr. White and Mr. Fring do.

Him working for Saul helps his true employer, Mr. Fring.

Before Walt and Jesse entered the picture, we have no information about how often Mike did jobs for Saul. After Walt and Jesse became clients, continuing to work for Saul provided Mike with the opportunity to keep better tabs on the pair.

Saul likely works with lots of other drug dealers/junkies as well. Having Mike on Saul's payroll would allow Fring access information about them. Information that could be useful to Fring and his drug operations.

Comment: Mike is legally employed by Los Pollos Hermanos, in charge of corporate security. This is later discussed when Hank and Steve are interrogating him. As such, he already has a source of legal income.